# Confusion on boundedness of sequences in real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**First**, we know that a convergent sequence has to be bounded. It's okay for me. Also boundedness definition for a sequence is : 
$$\exists M \in \mathbb {R^+} \ \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb N \ \ \ \ |a_n|\leq M $$
$1 \over {n-1} $ sequence is convergent but how can it be bounded? The term $a_1$ is not bounded.

I know it is so so basic but if someone illuminate me I will be appreciated.

**Second**, I need an example for bounded subsequence of an unbounded sequence.
Let $a_n=tan(\frac{n\pi}{2})$  It is an unbounded sequence but if I take a subsequence with even natural numbers, it will be a constant sequence of $0$ and it is bounded. Is it a correct example?

**Edit:** I got my two points above but I cannot find a basic example for unbounded sequence can have bounded subsequence. Could someone please give an easy example?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: $a_n = 1/(n-1)$ is not *defined* for $n=1$.

Comment: And $\tan(n\pi/2)$ is not defined for odd $n$.

Comment: Ok. I got these 2 points but I cannot find an example easily for unbounded sequence can have a bounded subsequence

Comment: Take for example the sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_{2n}=0$ (even indices) and $a_{2n+1}=2^{2n+1}$ (odd indices). Then clearly the sequence is not bounded, but the subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ with  $n_k$ selecting only even indices is bounded (actually always equal to zero).

Comment: As pointed out by the others, a real sequence must be defined for all indices, i.e. $a_n\in R$ for all $n$.

Comment: (I saw your edit, so I've posted the previous as a possible answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example the sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_{2n}=0$ (even indices) and $a_{2n+1}=2^{2n+1}$ (odd indices). Then clearly the sequence is not bounded, but the subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ with  $n_k$ selecting only even indices is bounded (actually always equal to zero).